# Need help identifying a part

Tags: capacitor, identification

[image]

I’ve got a couple of wireless LEDs that I want to replicate for project I’m working on. The only problem is I’m still very new to all this and I am struggling to grasp some concepts. Since I learn best hands-on I figured I'd dive in and see what I can learn.

With that said I need help identifying what I think is a capacitor, and determining what its value is (or at least how I would go about figuring it out).

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138131/discussion-on-question-by-dylan-degering-need-help-identifying-a-part).

Answer (score 0):

It's a capacitor, and like most surface mount capacitors unmarked. you'll have to measure its capacitance after disassembling the circuit.